# error with f# generic follow Expert Fsharp book example

Tags: f#

I'm reading Expert F# book and I found this code

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let divideIntoEquivalenceClasses keyf seq =
// The dictionary to hold the equivalence classes
  let dict = new Dictionary<'key,ResizeArray<'T>>()
  // Build the groupings
  seq |> Seq.iter (fun v ->
                          let key = keyf v
                          let ok,prev = dict.TryGetValue(key)
                          if ok then prev.Add(v)
                          else let prev = new ResizeArray<'T>()
                             dict.[key] <- prev
                             prev.Add(v))

 dict |> Seq.map (fun group -> group.Key, Seq.readonly group.Value)
```

and the example use:

```
> divideIntoEquivalenceClasses (fun n -> n % 3) [ 0 .. 10 ];;
val it : seq<int * seq<int>>
= seq [(0, seq [0; 3; 6; 9]); (1, seq [1; 4; 7; 10]); (2, seq [2; 5; 8])]
```

first for me this code is really ugly, even if this is safe, It looks more similar to imperative languages than to functional lang..specially compared to clojure. But the problem is not this...I'm having problems with the Dictionary definition

when I type this:

```
let dict = new Dictionary<'key,ResizeArray<'T>>();;
```

I get this:

```
pruebafs2a.fs(32,5): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'dict' has been inferred to have generic type
val dict : Dictionary<'_key,ResizeArray<'_T>> when '_key : equality    

Either define 'dict' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

is It ok?...

thanks so much

---

**improve question:**

Ok I've been reading about value restriction and I found this helpfull information

> In particular, only function definitions and simple immutable data
>   expressions are automatically generalized

...ok..this explains why

```
let dict = new Dictionary<'key,ResizeArray<'T>>();;
```

doesn't work...and show 4 different techniques, although in my opinion they only resolve the error but aren't solutions for use generic code:

**Technique 1: Constrain Values to Be Nongeneric**

```
 let empties : int list [] = Array.create 100 []
```

**Technique 3: Add Dummy Arguments to Generic Functions When Necessary**

```
let empties () = Array.create 100 []
let intEmpties : int list [] = empties()
```

**Technique 4: Add Explicit Type Arguments When Necessary (similar to tec 3)**

```
let emptyLists = Seq.init 100 (fun _ -> [])
> emptyLists<int>;;
val it : seq<int list> = seq [[]; []; []; []; ...]
```

**-----    and the only one than let me use real generic code   ------
Technique 2: Ensure Generic Functions Have Explicit Arguments**

```
let mapFirst = List.map fst //doesn't work
let mapFirst inp = List.map fst inp
```

Ok, in 3 of 4 techniques I need resolve the generic code before can work with this...now...returning to book example...when the compile knows the value for 'key and 'T

let dict = new Dictionary<'key,ResizeArray<'T>>()

in **the scope the code is very generic for let key be any type, the same happen with 'T**

**and the biggest dummy question is** :

when I enclose the code in a function (technique 3):

```
let empties = Array.create 100 [] //doesn't work
let empties () = Array.create 100 []
val empties : unit -> 'a list []

I need define the type before begin use it
let intEmpties : int list [] = empties()
```

for me (admittedly I'm a little dummy with static type languages) this is not real generic because it can't infer the type when I use it, I need define the type and then pass values (not define its type based in the passed values) exist other way define type without be so explicit..

**thanks so much..really appreciate any help**

Comment: Note on the update - it is very rare to run in to value restriction errors in real code, the inferrence can usually pick things up from usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
let dict = new Dictionary<'key,ResizeArray<'T>>();;
```

fails because when you type the `;;` the compiler doesn't know what `'key` and `'T` are.  As the error message states you need to add a type annotation, or allow the compiler to infer the type by using it later or make it a function

Examples

Type annotation change

```
let dict = new Dictionary<int,ResizeArray<int>>();;
```

Using types later

```
let dict = new Dictionary<'key,ResizeArray<'T>>()
dict.[1] <- 2
```

using a function

```
let dict() = new Dictionary<'key,ResizeArray<'T>>();;
```

Comment: thanks john but it isn't totally clear for me now...when I write dict inside the function the compiles doesn't know what are the 'key and 'T type...this function works with number, letters, etc. actually I need an: val dict : Dictionary<'_key,ResizeArray<'_T>> when '_key : equality, please if you can give more details or some link with more details...thanks!!

Comment: @user1050817 : Functions can be generic, values cannot. `dict` is instantiated with the function's generic argument types.

Comment: @ildjarn - It's not quite true that values can't be generic (e.g. try `([],[])`), it's just that the set of heuristics for identifying the safe creation of generic values is very limited.

Comment: @user1050817 - the key is that when you are in the function the compiler has extra information that it doesn't.  When you type `;;` into `fsi` the compiler has to make a function call and cannot determine the correct generic dictionary - so you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

> for me this code is really ugly, even if this is safe, It looks more similar to imperative languages than to functional lang.

I agree completely – it's slightly tangential to your direct question, but I think a more idiomatic (*functional*) approach would be:

```
let divideIntoEquivalenceClasses keyf seq =
    (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(), seq)
    ||> Seq.fold (fun dict v ->
        let key = keyf v
        match dict.TryGetValue key with
        | false, _ -> dict.Add (key, ResizeArray(Seq.singleton v))
        | _, prev  -> prev.Add v
        dict)
    |> Seq.map (function KeyValue (k, v) -> k, Seq.readonly v)
```

This allows sufficient type inference to obviate the need for your question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This actually doesn't cause an issue when it's defined all together. That is, select the entire block that you posted and send it to FSI in one go. I get this:

```
val divideIntoEquivalenceClasses :
  ('T -> 'key) -> seq<'T> -> seq<'key * seq<'T>> when 'key : equality
```

However, if you type these individually into FSI then as John Palmer says there is not enough information in that isolated line for the interpreter to determine the type constraints. John's suggestions will work, but the original code is doing it correctly - defining the variable and using it in the same scope so that the types can be inferred.

Comment: than yamen but it's precisely I can't understand..why this is valid:    """val divideIntoEquivalenceClasses :
  ('T -> 'key) -> seq<'T> -> seq<'key * seq<'T>> when 'key : equality"""    and this not:     """val dict : Dictionary<'_key,ResizeArray<'_T>> when '_key : equality"""       when I define "dict" inside the function this hasn't enough information about the type neither...this must work with letter, numbers, etc...but I can't why sometimes work and other times not...thanks for the help!!...

Comment: I think you need to read the answer from @kvb - there is a massive difference between a program of two lines and a program of one line in F#. The compiler needs information *further along* in the program to ensure it knows the right constraints to infer on a type. If you try to type and compile (send to FSI) the program one line at a time, it does not always have enough information to infer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The workarounds proposed by the other answers are all good.  Just to clarify based on your latest updates, let's consider two blocks of code:

```
let empties = Array.create 100 []
```

as opposed to:

```
let empties = Array.create 100 []
empties.[0] <- [1]
```

In the second case, the compiler can infer that `empties : int list []`, because we are inserting an `int list` into the array in the second line, which constrains the element type.

It sounds like you'd like the compiler to infer a generic value `empties : 'a list []` in the first case, but this would be unsound.  Consider what would happen if the compiler did that and we then entered the following two lines in another batch:

```
empties.[0] <- [1] // treat 'a list [] as int list []
List.iter (printfn "%s") empties.[0] // treat 'a list [] as string list []
```

Each of these lines unifies the generic type parameter `'a` with a different concrete type (`int` and `string`).  Either of these unifications is fine in isolation, but they are incompatible with each other and would result in treating the `int` value `1` inserted by the first line as a `string` when the second line is executed, which is clearly a violation of type safety.

Contrast this with an empty list, which really is generic:

```
let empty = []
```

Then in this case, the compiler *does* infer `empty : 'a list`, because it's safe to treat empty as a list of different types in different locations in your code without ever impacting type safety:

```
let l1 : int list = empty
let l2 : string list = empty
let l3 = 'a' :: empty
```

In the case where you make `empties` the return value of a generic function:

```
let empties() = Array.create 100 []
```

it is again safe to infer a generic type, since if we try our problematic scenario from before:

```
empties().[0] <- [1]
List.iter (printfn "%s") (empties().[0])
```

we are creating a *new* array on each line, so the types can be different without breaking the type system.
Hopefully this helps explain the reasons behind the limitation a bit more.